# Two related comboboxes in c# populating from database

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I am having this problem:

I have two `combobox`'s that are populated through datasets with different tables in database, the first one has items, the second one has brands that are shown based on the item ID chosen in the first `combo box`.

For example, TV with the ID = 1 is chosen in the first combo box,
the second is populated with Brands which have ItemId = 1 for example Samsung, LG, Ext.

I have tried with two different datasets but i cannot relate WHERE condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have the following two tables:

[image]

[image]

I would populate the first ComboBox like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = db.BRAND.Select(c => c.NAME).ToList();
```

I would then implement the following event handler:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> d = db.BRAND.ToDictionary(c => c.NAME, c => c.ID);
    comboBox2.DataSource = (from c in db.ITEM
                            where c.BRAND_ID == d[comboBox1.Text]
                            select c.NAME).ToList();
}
```

This assumes the brand names are unique, however.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
 DataRow[] drSelectedRows = YourDataTable.Select("itemid = "+yourvalue);
```

or

```
 DataView dv = new DataView(YourDataTable);
  dv.RowFilter ="itemid = "+yourvalue;
```